# Regex to match if no space is found

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this:

```
^.*(?!.*[^\S])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

And this does not match if the string has a space at the end.

I'm trying to make it so that it matches only if the string does not have a space anywhere, not just at the end. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you trim leading/trailing spaces before you check the regex?

Comment: How about simply: `^[\S]+$` ?

Comment: `!/\s/g.test("YOUR STRING");`

Comment: @MElliott This works. You can get more points if you officially answer the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about simply:

```
^[\S]+$
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/yA6xU3

Comment: No need for the `[...]`, `\S` is already a range of characters. `^\S+$` will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest expression to match a non-empty string with no blank characters:

```
^\S+$
```